# Top 5 Employees from each dept with lowest attendance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I find top 5 employees from each department with lowest attendance?

**---Employee Table**

[image: EmployeeTable]

**--- Department Table**

[image: DepartmentTable]

**--- Attendance Table**

[image: AttendanceTable]

I tried in this way to find top 5 salary from each department but how to apply in this specially for attendance table with employee and department table how to find top 5 employees with lowest attendance please assist me in this regard with cte.

Thanks

```
With ctetemp As
(
    Select E.EmpId, E.Ename, E.Salary,D.Dname, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY D.DeptId ORDER BY Salary desc) as rnw
    from EmployeeTbl AS E JOIN Departmet AS D
    ON   D.DeptId = e.Dept_Id_Emp
)
Select * from ctetemp
where rnw IN (5)
```

Comment: Your attempt makes no reference to the table `attendance` so won't be used. What are your expected results here? How do the rows in the table `attendance` effect your expected results? Don't post images of data either, take the time to supply DDL and DML statements and/or tabular formatted `text`.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Pictures of data don't help us help you, nor does having us guess at data types.

Comment: You haven't included the results you expect for your sample data. Since most of the employees have no records in the attendance table, they must have never been present. Does that make them the lowest attendance?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference the attendance table.

I'm assuming 'a' means 'absent' in this context.

```
SELECT
  AbsenceSummary.DeptID
 ,AbsenceSummary.EmpId
 ,AbsenceSummary.AbsentDays
 ,AbsenceSummary.AbsentRank
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      dept.DeptId
     ,att.EmpId
     ,COUNT(*) AS AbsentDays
     ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dept.DeptId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS AbsentRank
    FROM
      attendance att
    INNER JOIN
      employee emp
        ON emp.EmpID = att.EmpId
    INNER JOIN
      department dept
        ON dpt.DeptId = emp.DeptId
    WHERE
      dept.DeptId IN (<the departments you care about>)
        AND att.atdate >= <your minimum date>
        AND att.atdate <= <your maximum date>
        AND att.attendance = 'a' --absent
    GROUP BY
      dept.DeptId
     ,att.EmpId
  ) AbsenceSummary
WHERE
  AbsenceSummary.AbsentRank <= 5
```

For the record, the `AtId` column in this situation is useless and possibly counterproductive.  The key is `(EmpId,atDate)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. have some issues to understand about derived table and CTE. got confused when solve some queries like big queries in such scenario what will be the approach about so please please let me know exact approach how to apply  when solve some queries with CTE and Derive Table.. give me some real world example

Comment: CTE/derived table is just a different way of writing the syntax.  It will return the same result as a subselect with the same code block.